# Creating a random number generating using user inputted number range. (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a random number game. One of the elements that I need is a random number generator that allows the user to set the range of which the number will be chosen from. Currently I have this and it does not work. Any tips?

JavaScript

```
var min = document.getElementById("minNum").value;
var max = document.getElementById("maxNum").value;

function setRandomNum() {
document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="minNum" name="minNum" />
<input type="text" id="maxNum" name="maxNum">
<input type="button" id="submitRange" name="submitRange" value="Set Range" onclick="setRandomNum()">
```

For now the document.write is there just to test if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the values of the inputs on document load i.e not when the button is pressed and as mentioned in the comments, `value` is a string so you have to parse it like so :

```js
function setRandomNum() {

  var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minNum").value);
  var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxNum").value);
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min))
  document.write(randomNum);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="minNum" name="minNum" />
<input type="text" id="maxNum" name="maxNum">
<input type="button" id="submitRange" name="submitRange" value="Set Range" onclick="setRandomNum()">
```

Comment: You may also want to mention that the `value` is a string, not a number, and use a radix to ensure a decimal number...

Comment: @thisOneGuy So in addition to the code above, would I have to do something like create a new variable such as this? 
var randomNum = parseFloat(setRandomNum);

Comment: what are you trying to do ? I think i see. Just do var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)); ill append to answer

Comment: @thisOneGuy Sorry, I'm a bit new to javaScript. But I was trying to ensure a number like David Thomas said. So, would the code that was added suffice?

Comment: parseInt(stringToChange); parses a string to an integer as long as it's made up of int's. So yes, this would insure its a number. Otherwise it wouldn't do the calculation.

Comment: @thisOneGuy, sorry to be a bother but I have one more thing to double check. If I wanted to use the value that was generated, would I just do return(randomNum)  ?

Comment: use the variable randomNum as that is your generated number. If you want to use this outside the function, declare the variable outside, i.e var randomNum; and then set it in the function, i.e randomNum = docu.... and so on. That way is not just seen by this function but by all functions made after you declare the variable. Make sense ?

Comment: so in order to do that you would just do  var randomNum;
 

function setRandomNum() {
 var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("minNum").value);
 var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("maxNum").value);
 randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min))
}

Comment: yes thats the best way if you want to use the number that is generated on button press but if you want to run the function and get the number back just return randomNum in the function and call the function on a variable like so : var callingRandomFunction = setRandomNum(); which will get the randomNumber and assign it to 'callingRandomFunction'

Comment: The subtracting, `(max - min)`, will force the string to be parsed as an integer regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Your calls to document.getElementById are outside the function, so they are not executed in time.

```
function setRandomNum() {
    var min = document.getElementById("minNum").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("maxNum").value;
    document.write(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I voted for `thisOneGuy` solution. But I recommend to put the `getElementId` outside the function for performance:

```
var minElement = document.getElementById("minNum");
var maxElement = document.getElementById("maxNum");

function setRandomNum () {
  var max, min, random;

  max = parseInt(maxElement.value);
  min = parseInt(minElement.value);
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min));

  document.write(random);
}
```